# Info and Debug Unified Logging messages not appearing in console when running iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, logging

I can't see **Debug** level or **Info** level log messages in the console app when running from the the iOS simulator.

- I **can see** Default, Error and Fault levels in the console with the simulator.
- I **can see** all **Debug**, **Info**, Default, Error and Fault levels in the console with a real non-simulated device.
- I'm using the same console app filter settings with the simulator and in a real device.

I'm using XCode 8.3.3 with a simulator running iOS 10.3.

I'm using the Unified Logging System in my iOS app, as described here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/

How can I get these **Debug** level and **Info** level log messages to display when running against the simulator?

Answer (score 7):

In the Console app's menu:
*Action ->Include Info Messages* and/or *->Include Debug Messages*

**Update:**
If you still don't see the messages, try entering this Terminal command to configure the logging levels for your app:

```
sudo log config --subsystem com.mydomain.appname --mode level:debug
```

This turns on `.debug`-level logging for subsystem "com.mydomain.appname" (which includes `.info` and `.default` messages).

Separately, if you want to persist the messages, rather than the default of memory-only, turn on persistence for the three levels at the same time, like so:

```
sudo log config --subsystem com.mydomain.appname --mode level:debug,persist:debug
```

(subset of [my answer at *Viewing os_log messages in device console*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48229691/1107226))

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the expected behaviour, unfortunately I can't point to any documentation to back this up, however the Info and Debug level log messages are sent to Xcode's console, not the Console.app.